# How to break external links of Excel files with Aspose.Cells for C++

Tags: c++, excel, hyperlink, external, aspose

I have been searching over [this documentation](https://docs.aspose.com/display/cellscpp/Developer+Guide) for instructions on how to break external links of Excel files, but with no success.

How can I break external links of Excel files with Aspose.Cells for C++ ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you may remove the external links in the Excel spreadsheet rather than breaking the hyperlinks. See the sample code for your reference:
e.g

**Sample code:**

```
void RemoveExternalLinksTest()
{
intrusive_ptr<IWorkbook> workbook = Factory::CreateIWorkbook(sourcePath->StringAppend(new String("ExternalLinksTest.xlsx")));
if(workbook->HasExernalLinks())
workbook->RemoveExternalLinks();
workbook->Save(resultPath->StringAppend(new String("ExternalLinksTest-Ret.xlsx")));
}
```

PS. I am working as Support developer/ Evangelist at Aspose.